# Janusgraph Gremlin addE created different vertices id after index implemented

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I am new to janusgraph and gremlin, when I try to create an edge with two existing vertices, I expect the return edge information, the edge source and end vertices id should be the same as I used to create the edge, however, it is not, two new ids are return. Moreover, when I try to find the edges connecting to one of the vertex ("tom"), I found that ("tom") has an edge connecting from and to it-self with has a different id, but the vertice count is just 2.

```
gremlin> g.V().count()
==>0
gremlin> tom = g.addV("party").property("name", "Tom").property("identity_number", "01234567")\
.property("identity_type", "PASSPORT").property("identity_country", "USA").next()
==>v[57402]
gremlin> mary = g.addV("party").property("name", "Mary").property("identity_number", "76543210")\
.property("identity_type", "PASSPORT").property("identity_country", "USA").next()
==>v[61626]
gremlin> g.V(tom).addE('relationship').to(mary)
==>e[3k4-18ci-80et-1bia][57474-relationship->61570]
gremlin> g.V(tom).bothE().otherV().path().by(__.valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens))
==>path[{id=57402, label=party, identity_country=[USA], identity_number=[01234567],\
 identity_type=[PASSPORT], name=[Tom]}, {id=3k4-18ci-80et-1bia, label=relationship},\
 {id=57474, label=party, identity_country=[USA], identity_number=[01234567], identity_type=[PASSPORT],\
 name=[Tom]}]
gremlin> g.V().count()
==>2
```

Could anyone tell me if this is  a normal situation? or if there is some configuration make this happened?

Many Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

I find that this situation is happened after I implemented the janusgraph index by the following code:

```
m = amlGraph.openManagement();

party = m.makeVertexLabel('party').partition().make();
relationship = m.makeEdgeLabel('relationship').make();

identity_country_key = m.makePropertyKey('identity_country').dataType(String.class).make();
identity_number_key = m.makePropertyKey('identity_number').dataType(String.class).make();
identity_type_key = m.makePropertyKey('identity_type').dataType(String.class).make();
name_key = m.makePropertyKey('name').dataType(String.class).make();
first_seen_datetime_key = m.makePropertyKey('first_seen_datetime').dataType(Date.class).make();
relationship_type_key = m.makePropertyKey('relationship_type').dataType(String.class).make();

party = m.getVertexLabel('party');
identity_country_key = m.getPropertyKey('identity_country');
identity_number_key = m.getPropertyKey('identity_number');
identity_type_key = m.getPropertyKey('identity_type');
name_key = m.getPropertyKey('name');
m.buildIndex('partyMixed', Vertex.class).addKey(identity_country_key, Mapping.TEXTSTRING.asParameter(), Parameter.of('identity_country', 'identity_country')).addKey(identity_number_key, Mapping.TEXTSTRING.asParameter(), Parameter.of('identity_number', 'identity_number')).addKey(identity_type_key, Mapping.TEXTSTRING.asParameter(), Parameter.of('identity_type', 'identity_type')).addKey(name_key, Mapping.TEXTSTRING.asParameter(), Parameter.of('name', 'name')).indexOnly(party).buildMixedIndex('search');

relationship = m.getEdgeLabel('relationship');
first_seen_datetime_key = m.getPropertyKey('first_seen_datetime');
relationship_type_key = m.getPropertyKey('relationship_type');
m.buildIndex('relationshipMixed', Edge.class).addKey(first_seen_datetime_key).addKey(relationship_type_key).indexOnly(relationship).buildMixedIndex('search');

m.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of JanusGraph are you using ? May be if you are using an older version it can be a bug...

I used one of the latest version(0.5.3) and tried to generate the same scenario and I am getting the correct ID.

```
    gremlin> 
    gremlin> tom = g.addV("party").property("name", "Tom").property("identity_number", "01234567").property("identity_type", "PASSPORT").property("identity_country", "USA").next()
    ==>v[4112]
    gremlin> 
    gremlin> mary = g.addV("party").property("name", "Mary").property("identity_number", "76543210").property("identity_type", "PASSPORT").property("identity_country", "USA").next()
    ==>v[40964232]
    gremlin> 
    gremlin> g.V(tom).addE('relationship').to(mary)
    ==>e[2rm-368-3ehh-oe07c][4112-relationship->40964232]
    gremlin>
```

Comment: I am using janusgraph version 0.6.1 and gremlin version 1.21.0, which are come from the docke "image:docker.io/janusgraph/janusgraph:latest"

Comment: Did you tried using some other version of the image ? Try once. May be it's the issue of the image.

Comment: No, but i just find that this situation happened after I implement the janusgraph index

Comment: Okay. Try reindexing the indexes. It may resolve this.

Comment: I tried, re-indexing the indexes doesn't solve the issue. Extra id for the existing vertex is still generated when creating edge with the vertex after re-index.